# Причины PHPExcel_Reader_Exception

Tags: php, исключения, phpexcel

Собствено сама ошибка

```
Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open C:\OpenServer\domains\kinopoisk\phpexel\Страницы с сылками2.xls for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\OpenServer\domains\kinopoisk\phpexel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5.php:433
```

собственно сам код

```
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
$sPath = dirname(__FILE__);
$sInFile = $sPath.'\Сериалы с сылками2.xls';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$oExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($sInFile);
$iStart = 2;
$aRes = array();

for ($i= $iStart; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $oRow = new stdClass();
    $oRow->id = $oExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $i)->getValue();
    $aRes[] = $oRow;
        }
var_dump($aRes);
```

Comment: Скорее всего, дело в кириллице и/или в пробелах в пути. Попробуйте попереименовывать файл.

Comment: @АлексейУколов да странно не знал оформляйте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, дело в кириллице и/или в пробелах в пути. На Windows это частая проблема. Попробуйте попереименовывать файл.